# Error maven install

Tags: maven, dependencies, installation

Help me find the reason.

**Content POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>biz.justtrust</groupId>
    <artifactId>smssender</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>smssender AMP project</name>
    <packaging>amp</packaging>
    <description>Manages the lifecycle of the smssender AMP (Alfresco Module Package)</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- 
       | SDK properties have sensible defaults in the SDK parent,
       | but you can override the properties below to use another version. 
       | For more available properties see the alfresco-sdk-parent POM. 
       -->
    <properties>
        <!-- Defines the alfresco edition to compile against. Allowed values are [org.alfresco|org.alfresco.enterprise]--> 
        <alfresco.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.groupId>
        <!-- Defines the alfresco version to compile against -->
        <alfresco.version>4.2.f</alfresco.version>
        <app.log.root.level>WARN</app.log.root.level>
        <alfresco.data.location>alf_data_dev</alfresco.data.location>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR artifactId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
        .    | Allowed values: alfresco | share. Defaults to a repository AMP, but could point to your foundation WAR -->
        <alfresco.client.war>alfresco</alfresco.client.war>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR groupId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
        .    | Could be org.alfresco | org.alfresco.enterprise or your corporate groupId -->
        <alfresco.client.war.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.client.war.groupId>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR version to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch -->
        <alfresco.client.war.version>4.2.f</alfresco.client.war.version>
        <!-- This controls which properties will be picked in src/test/properties for embedded run -->
        <env>local</env>
    </properties>

    <!-- Here we realize the connection with the Alfresco selected platform 
        (e.g.version and edition) -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- This will import the dependencyManagement for all artifacts in the selected Alfresco version/edition
                (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) 
                NOTE: You still need to define dependencies in your POM, but you can omit version as it's enforced by this dependencyManagement. NOTE: It defaults 
                to the latest version this SDK pom has been tested with, but alfresco version can/should be overridden in your project's pom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>alfresco-platform-distribution</artifactId>
                <version>${alfresco.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Following dependencies are needed for compiling Java code in src/main/java; 
         <scope>provided</scope> is inherited for each of the following; 
         for more info, please refer to alfresco-platform-distribution POM -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.smslib</groupId>
            <artifactId>smslib</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxtxcomm</artifactId>
            <version>2.2pre2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/RXTXcomm.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
            <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- This repository is only needed to retrieve Alfresco parent POM. 
        NOTE: This can be removed when/if Alfresco will be on Maven Central 

        NOTE: The repository to be used for Alfresco Enterprise artifacts is
        https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/private/. Please check
        with Alfresco Support to get credentials to add to your ~/.m2/settings.xml
        if you are a Enterprise customer or Partner  
        -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>alfresco-public</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>smslib</id>
            <url>http://smslib.org/maven2/v3</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>alfresco-public-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.alfresco.maven.plugin
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            alfresco-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.1.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>set-version</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Output console**

[INFO] Building smssender AMP project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://smslib.org/maven2/v3/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to smslib (http://smslib.org/maven2/v3): smslib.org: С именем узла не связано ни одного адреса
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from http://smslib.org/maven2/v3 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of smslib has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to smslib (http://smslib.org/maven2/v3): smslib.org: С именем узла не связано ни одного адреса
[INFO] Downloading: http://smslib.org/maven2/v3/org/smslib/smslib/3.5.4/smslib-3.5.4.pom

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project smssender: Could not resolve dependencies for project biz.justtrust:smssender:amp:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.smslib:smslib:jar:3.5.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.smslib:smslib:jar:3.5.4: Could not transfer artifact org.smslib:smslib:pom:3.5.4 from/to smslib (http://smslib.org/maven2/v3): smslib.org: Unknown host smslib.org

Comment: The whole domain is not accessible to not for Maven...

Comment: To clarify: your project tries to use some dependency, which should be downloaded from smslib.org (whatever that website is). Unfortunately, that website is unavailable, so Maven fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error shows "Unknown host smslib.org". And you also defined your repository as

```
 <repository>
        <id>smslib</id>
        <url>http://smslib.org/maven2/v3</url>
  </repository>
```

Please check if you could reach smslib.org.